# limited fieldset in salesforce user object for lookup query

Tags: lookup

I need to get the owner's information when I run query for other salesforce object.

For example, I am able to run the query [SELECT  owner.email,owner.phone FROM task]
successfully.

However, the query [SELECT  owner.email,owner.phone,owner.mobilephone FROM task ] is failed and the error message shows "No such column 'mobilephone' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

I didn't find any documentation in salesforce about this limit.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting that the Force IDE .schema view suggests that the Owner field is a reference to a User but not all User fields appear to be queryable in this way. Perhaps someone has an explanation...

Comment: You should have any field on user. It seems likely that you have a syntax error in your code that we can't see. Can you post it exactly as it appears?

Comment: if you run SELECT email,phone,mobilephone FROM user, it  works, however, SELECT owner.email,owner.phone,owner.mobilephone FROM task doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this interesting link and superfell's answer may explain the issue you see: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008wAvIAI

Owner on Task is a polymorphic relationship (i.e. to can be a foreign key to different types), for these types of relationships only a subset of data of the related object is exposed, these are fields defined on the Name entity, including firstName, lastName & phone, but not all fields from user. **From the schema you can see this because the ownerId field has the isNamePointing property set to true(hence you can see this in the schema)**. There's also a give-away in the error message where it says the field is not valid for the Name entity. This is all covered in the SOQL-R section of the API documentation.

So if you cannot do it the above way how do you do it? See this link : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009EkBIAU

Summary of how to do :

- Query for the Tasks you care about
- Loop through the results and compile a set of User ID's
- Query for data on the users matching the compiled set of ID's
- Run your logic on the Tasks you retrieved, using the User ID to look up the associated user information when needed